# How to display nested objects values in a template on a child component in Angular2?

Tags: json, angular, service, view

I've been stuck with one problem - I'm getting JSON from my service class, I am able to write to the console whole object, I'm able to display root level values, but for the nested values I get `[object Object]` or nothing at all; depends on various approaches.

I was trying to find a solution across StackOverflow and they all seemed to point for using pipes. Would that be something that you suggest in my case as well?

Here is my code:

[image: item-list.component.ts]

[image: method in service class]

In a parent component I simply pass the object to child:

```
`<app-item *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" [item]="item[itemId]="i"></app-item> `
```

On a child class I have

```
@Input() item: Item;
```

And finally on a child html template I have the following structure:

```
<a [routerLink]="[itemId]" class="list-group-item clearfix" routerLinkActive="active">
    <div class="pull-left" (click)="stateInfo()">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ item.name }}</h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text">Item code : {{ item.code }}</p>
        <p class="list-group-item-text">Item tag : {{ item?.tags }}</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

I'vealso tried to extend like `{{ item?.tags[i].name }}` and various other ways I can think of but none seems to be working.

Tags entity is optional, hence the '?' in a path.

I also attached click event listener, so I can console.log(this.item). This is what I get in the console:

```
Object:
    code: "001"
    name: "Kitchen"
    tags: Array[2]
        0: Object
            name: "tag1"
            value: "32"
        1: Object
            name: "tag2"
            value: "44"
...
```

As I understand you have your service as your middle layer between your DB and the view. You inject service in your component, then you call a method that is in your service (from your component). Your service is responsible for getting the data (using http) and mapping it to json. Your component is subscribing to the response, converts json to array and through interpolation is showing to the view. Right?

Comment: What is `[item]="item[itemId]="i"` supposed to do? That's invalid HTML. Perhaps you meant `[item]="item"`?

Comment: have you tried an ngRepeat on item.tags?

Comment: Gunter Zochbauer - it suppose to be [item]="item" [itemId]="i". Mistake in question.

Comment: Stephan - {{ item.tags }} returns me [object Object] for each value it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tags are an array, so you would need to iterate that array and display them.

First, let's fix an error in your parent template:

```
[item]="item[itemId]="i"
```

is wrong. As you can see in your template you are iterating `let item of items`... so on that same line you can just pass the current `item` in the itreration, so simply pass that single (current) item:

```
[item]="item"
```

Then to iterating the tags. As mentioned it is an array, so you just iterate through it like you did with the items:

```
<p *ngFor="let tag of item.tags">{{tag.name}}</p>
```

That should work! :) Here's a [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/pmXbTihBGiiJVwTcyEPF?p=preview)

As a sidenote, is there a special reason why you are iterating through the items and assigning them to a new array and then back to the `items` array? Why not simply do:

```
.subscribe(data => {
  this.items = data;
})
```

Comment: AJT_82 - thank you very much! Exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you for correcting the mistake on a parent template. I knew I had that object available, and second iteration was like a light bulb.   As for assigning to a new array  - I was simply following this from a tutorial.

Comment: You are very welcome! Glad I could help! If it solved your issue, consider accepting the answer :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: It did solved the issue! Quick question - if my items will have 100-200 tags (not necceserally eachitem) would it be better to make another http.get call just for tags (maybe from different location), instead of getting everything from the db and displaying only what is desired in a view? Or angular2 is so fast that when I reach a point of worry there will be already angular6-7?

Comment: Well, since you are getting the items, it comes with the whole payload, tags and all in one request. This is more of a backend question I would say. Will you just separate the tags from the items in the backend, and then just get the tags of a specific item/items you are interested in based on the item id in a separate request? But as said, this is more of a backend question I would say. So currently the whole payload is there anyway. What you want to do with it, is up to you.

Comment: It really depends on your use case, how you are going to build this app, difficult to give a "best-practise-solution" based on so little information :)

Comment: But generally speaking, of course it's a huge payload to get if you have much data. I would think you wouldn't display all items with all tags on your page. So in that sense it would be wise to separate the tags from the items, and have sort of a detail view, when you click on an item, a request is made to the api to retrieve the tags belonging to that particular item.

Comment: Hey AJT_82, really appreciate your answer. I do agree its best to make another request in case I need to show tags associated with the item. Probably will know if this is good approach or not once the app go live :)